# How to secure ConnectionString and/or AppSettings in asp.net core (on-prem)

Tags: security, asp.net-core, connection-string, appsettings

First off, I know we dont have ConnectionStrings and AppSettings per se in .Net core, but in my case I want to encrypt a ConnectionString and maybe some other application configurations stored in my appsettings.json (or other settings file).

I know this has been discussed alot all over the internet, but no one seems to have a legit answer..
So suggestions that has beeen thrown out there are:

- Using EnvironmentConfigurationBuilder, however... that doesnt really solve the issue, since we just moved our plain text configurations from appsettings.json to the Env-variables)
- Create a custom ConfigurationProvider that encrypts and decrypts the appsettings.json (or selective parts of it), however.. that doesnt solve the issue either, since we need to store our key(s) for the decryption somewhere accessible by our application, and even if we did store the key as a "hard-coded" string in our application, a "hacker" could simply just de-compile it.

Someone also mentioned that even if you do encrypt the appsettings.json, a "hacker" could always just do a memory dump and find the decrypted version of the data.. Im no expert on that field, so Im not sure how likely or how complicated such as thing would be.

Azure Key Vault has also been mentioned a few times, however.. in my case and in alot of cases when working with authorities, this is not an option since cloud-services are not allowed.

I might be overthinking this, since if an attacker/hacker actually has managed to get into our server, then we might have bigger issues.. but what would be the way to deal with this issue? Do you simply dont care and leave it all as "plain text"? Or should you take some sort if action and encrypt or obscure the secrets?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encrypt connection strings from your config file because the best way is still to NOT store this information in your config files but as environment variables on your server.

In your `appsettings.json` file just store your local development connection string. For other environments, on the server it is deployed set an environment variable with `__` (double underscore) for each child node in you config file.

You can read how this works on [this page](https://www.benday.com/2017/12/20/ef-core-asp-net-core-read-connections-strings-from-environment-variables/)

If you have a config file as follow

```
{ 
   "ConnectionStrings": { 
     "default": "Server=192.168.5.1; Database=DbContextFactorySample3; user id=database-user; password=Pa$$word;" 
   } 
}
```

On a Windows server you would set the value like this

```sh
set "ConnectionStrings__default=Server=the-production-database-server; Database=DbContextFactorySample2; Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

I don't know how is your deployment flow and tools you're using but it's worth digging into it and find how you can use of this feature.

For example if you're deploying on Kubernetes you could use [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to set your secret values.

At my company on TFS we create a Release pipeline and make use of the variables section to set the secret values. These values will then be used when the code is deployed on Kubernetes.
Variables in Release pipelines in TFS can be hidden like passwords and no developer can see the production values. Only administrators can

Comment: Yes, Im aware of EnvironmentConfigurationBuilder (as mentioned above).. however.. if your server gets compromised, your ConnectionString and other settings will be in plain text for the attacker to read (even if they are located in the environment-variables.. its just a few clicks away), I also use TFS (or Azure DevOps in my case) and the approach you mention to prevent "having" to check-in production secrets into the repo is exactly that approach I would use.. however.. as mentioned it still leaves the secrets as plain text and opens the "infrastructure" for additional attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Securing `appsettings.json` in an ASP.NET Core application is crucial, especially when it contains sensitive data like database connection strings, API keys, or any other secret values. Storing sensitive configuration settings in plaintext in `appsettings.json` is not recommended for security reasons. Here are some approaches to secure these settings:

#### Environment Variables

One of the simplest ways to manage sensitive configuration is through the use of environment variables. Environment variables are easy to change between deploys without changing any code, unlike config files.

```bash
# set an environment variable in a shell
export MySensitiveData="MyValue"
```

You can then access it in your code like this:

```cs
var mySensitiveData = Configuration["MySensitiveData"];
```

#### User Secrets (Development Only)

ASP.NET Core provides a feature known as 'User Secrets' intended for use only in the development environment. This allows developers to store and retrieve sensitive data without the data being added to source control.

```bash
dotnet user-secrets set "MySensitiveData" "MyValue"
```

To enable user secrets, you need to add a reference to the user secrets ID in your `csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>your-user-secrets-id-here</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

#### Azure Key Vault

If you're deploying your application on Azure, you can leverage Azure Key Vault for storing secrets, keys, and certificates.

First, add the necessary NuGet package:

```bash
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault
```

Then, modify your `Program.cs` to include Azure Key Vault in the configuration:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    builtConfig["AzureKeyVault:BaseUrl"],
                    keyVaultClient,
                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        });
```

#### Encryption

You could encrypt sensitive data and decrypt it when you read it back into your application. This is more complex and requires you to manage encryption keys.

#### Third-Party Tools

Several third-party tools and libraries, such as HashiCorp's Vault, can securely manage secrets for your application.

#### File Permissions

Ensure that whatever file or service you use to store secrets is locked down with the appropriate file permissions to prevent unauthorized access.

#### Never Store Secrets in Source Code

This should go without saying, but never store sensitive data in your source code or version control system.

By using one or a combination of these approaches, you can increase the security of your sensitive settings in ASP.NET Core.